# Why am i getting syntax error in this query in mysql

Tags: mysql

new to DB and I'm writing a query but need help to find out the syntax error.
Query:

```
SELECT IF (EXISTS(SELECT * FROM contact_address WHERE ad_ct_id = 1)) THEN
BEGIN
UPDATE contact_address set ad_city = 'Iraq'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
INSERT INTO contact_address (ad_ct_id, ad_type, ad_city)
VALUES (1, 'o', 'Iraq')
END
END IF;
```

Error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') THEN
BEGIN
UPDATE contact_address set ad_city = 'Iraq'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
INSERT I' at line 1
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Remove `SELECT`.

```
IF (EXISTS(SELECT * FROM contact_address WHERE ad_ct_id = 1)) THEN
BEGIN
    UPDATE contact_address set ad_city = 'Iraq'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO contact_address (ad_ct_id, ad_type, ad_city)
    VALUES (1, 'o', 'Iraq')
END
END IF;
```

Answer (score 0):

'why am I getting syntax error' - you cannot use if..end if outwith a stored program, mysql does not require begin..end within if..end if, the if syntax should be if exists(select..), every statement needs to be terminated.

Comment: IF EXISTS(
  SELECT
    *
  FROM
    contact_address
  WHERE
    ad_ct_id = 1
)
) THEN
UPDATE
  contact_address
set
  ad_city = 'Iraq' ELSE
INSERT INTO
  contact_address (ad_ct_id, ad_type, ad_city)
VALUES
  (1, 'o', 'Iraq');